# Django forms: error not displaying in json

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to set up my password forgot in Django using built-in validators, but I am getting no response if reproduce errors, but it supposed to show up the errors others classes, how can I fix this?

forms.py

```
class RestorePasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Password','required': True}))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Password','required': True}))
```

#### views

```
  def post(self, request,token):
    form = RestorePasswordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      obj = token(token)
      if obj:
        this_user = User.objects.get(id=obj.email_id)
        if not this_user:
          return False
        this_user.set_password(request.POST.get('new_password2'))
        this_user.save()
        obj.token = None
        obj.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message":form.errors})
```

browser response display 
 `{"message": {}}`

Answer (score -1):

When you are validating a form you should always check if it is posting and then only process it. Also 'forms.errors' is going to give you HTML string, but you already are aware of that.
The reason you are getting empty reason is because nothing is being posted to the form.

```
def post(self, request,token):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = RestorePasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        obj = token(token)
        if obj:
            this_user = User.objects.get(id=obj.email_id)
            if not this_user:
              return False
            this_user.set_password(request.POST.get('new_password2'))
            this_user.save()
            obj.token = None
            obj.save()
      else:
           print("you didn't post anything to form")
    return JsonResponse({"message":form.errors})
```